# Estou começando no python e queria consertar isso o sleep funciona direito mas aparece None

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
from time import sleep

print('\t ----TABUADA---- ')

numero = int(input("Informe um número para ver a tabuada: "))
print(f"Tabuda de {numero}: ")

for i in range(0,11):
    n_i = (numero * i)
    print(f"{sleep(1)} {numero} X {i} = {n_i}")
```

Comment: O `sleep(1)` deve ser usado fora do `print`. `None` é o retorno da função `sleep`. Na linha anterior ao `print` use apenas `sleep(1)` e na do print, altere para `print(f"{numero} X {i} = {n_i}")`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema é que você printou o sleep. Sleep não é um valor para ser printado.

O uso correto seria:

```
for i in range(0, 11):
    sleep(1)
    n_i = (numero * i)
    print(f"{numero} X {i} = {n_i}")
```

Comment: obg : import time
print('\t ----TABUADA---- ')

numero = int(input("Informe um número para ver a tabuada: "))
print(f"Tabuda de {numero}: ")

for i in range(0,11):
    n_i = (numero * i)
    print(f"{numero} X {i} = {n_i}")
    time.sleep(1)